# Android: onCreateOptionsMenu is called but actionbar menu isn't updated in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu

I am using `drawerlayout` in activity with several fragments. By clicking the navigation item, I switch the fragment this way:

```
switch (index) {
            case 0:
                if (checkinFragment == null) {
                    checkinFragment = new CheckinFragment();
                    ft.add(R.id.main_container, checkinFragment, "0");
                } else {
                    ft.show(checkinFragment);
                }

                break;
            case 3:
                if (jianGuanFragment == null) {
                    jianGuanFragment = new JianGuanFragment();
                    ft.add(R.id.main_container, jianGuanFragment, "3");
                } else {
                    ft.show(jianGuanFragment);
                }

                break;
        }

        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Each fragment has a different menu resource file inflated in its `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` method.

**Steps:** 
1. When first enter the activity the menu in `checkinFragment` is shown.(All right)
2. Then switch to the `jianGuanFragment`, the menu in `jianGuanFragment` is shown.(Also right)
3. However, when switch back to the first fragment(`checkinFragment`), the actionbar menu isn't updated. The showing menu is still the one in `jianGuanFragment`.  That's the problem.

And from the log I know the `onCreateOptionsMenu` in the showing fragment is called each time I switch to it. That's to say:

**onCreateOptionsMenu is called but actionbar menu isn't updated.**

Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot.

**EDIT 1: add the code in onCreateOptionsMenu:**
(1)in checkinFragment

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        LogUtils.e("TAG", "CheckinFragment onCreateOptionsMenu");
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_setting, menu);
    }
```

(2)in jianGuanFragment

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        LogUtils.e("TAG", "JianGuanFragment onCreateOptionsMenu");
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_jianguan, menu);
    }
```

**EDIT 2: I use toolbar, not the old actionbar.**

Comment: @unrealsoul007 I have already setHasOptionsMenu(true) in the `onActivityCreated` of each fragment. And I have tried writing it in onCreateOptionsMenu of the fragment just now, it didn't work.

Comment: can you try to use onPrepareOptionsMenu() in fragment

Answer (score 1):

At last I find the solution:

Each time entering a fragment, re-set the toolbar as ationbar again.

```
@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);

    if (!hidden) {
        AppCompatActivity compatActivity = (AppCompatActivity) mActivity;
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) compatActivity.findViewById(toolbarId);
        compatActivity.setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. You need to use it where call to `OnCreateOptionsMenu()` is required.

**EDIT:**
`getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()` can be used if you want to call it from `Fragment`.

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: invalidateOptionsMenu() not available in fragment I guess..?

Comment: Whether using `invalidateOptionsMenu()` or not, the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in current fragment will be called. The problem is even though the actionbar menu isn't updated.

Comment: Raghavendra Code Editted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
1)in checkinFragment

```
 @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();
        LogUtils.e("TAG", "CheckinFragment onCreateOptionsMenu");
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_setting, menu);
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
```